# Unexpected MongoServerError 11000 (duplicate) for a field that is NOT even declared in schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing an *online store* Node.js REST API with Mongoose (MongoDB), which I'm new to. I decided to test the *orders service* and saw that after I had made 1 successful order **(so it worked once)**, it sent me a *duplicate key error* for the next one, for a key 'name' with value 'null', of the order.products collection that is an **Array**, and not a kvp object.

I should note that **nowhere** in my code is *'products.name'* mentioned.

**ERROR**:

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: store.orders index: products.name_1 dup
at {...}{
   key: { products.name: null }
   index: 0,
   code: 11000,
   keyPattern: { 'products.name': 1 },
   keyValue: { 'products.name': null },
   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

when the error is handled, this message is received and it makes no sense:
`{ "message": "Order with products.name "null" already exists" }`

**Order schema**:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    address: {
        type: addressSchema,
        required: true
    },
    products: {
        type: [orderProductSchema],
        required: true,
        validate: nonEmptyArray
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        validate: inCollection(Object.values(ORDER_STATUS))
    },
    price: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0 }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

*don't bother with the validators or the address/status/user/price, it has nothing to do with them; what is more, nothing is specified as* `unique: true`

As you can see, the 'products' field is just an array of products, no 'name' is declared

**orderProductSchema**:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    product: {
        _id: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            maxLength: 250
        },
        displayImage: String,
        price: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0 }
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        validate: isInteger,
        min: 1
    },
}, { _id: false });
```

I have a 'name' field here, but it's just the name of a product. The error is thrown even when the names are unique.

**Orders service**:

```
    // get data and format it to fit the Order model
    console.dir(products); // --> all is how it's expected to be in the schema

    return await Order.create({
        userId,
        address,
        products,
        status: ORDER_STATUS.AWAITING_CONFIRMATION,
        price: totalOrderPrice
    });
```

It seems to me that this is some weird MongoDB behaviour/specification that I missed. If someone has any idea what could cause the problem - please help.

I tried removing all parts such as other fields and validations to see if they might've caused the problem but that was not the case. I thought maybe I had formatted the object I send to the database wrong, but I console.log-ed it and it was fine ({products: Array})

Comment: Mongoose enforces uniqueness by building the relevant unique index in the database. But that index can be built (and therefore present) in the database independently of Mongoose schema. Relatedly, my understanding is that changing the schema (eg to remove a unique constraint) does NOT remove the enforcing index in the database. In any case, the collection has a unique index and you will need to go drop it if it doesn't match your desired application logic

Comment: I agree with user20042973, looking at the error message, there appears to be an index "index: products.name_1" enforcing the unique key on product.name. Check if you still have that index in your database. You may need to manually drop this index.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user20042973 and @MTN I saw that my 'orders' database had index 'products.name' (no idea how it got there).. I just removed the index and the problem is solved.